# FitNesse - Environment Variables in Symbolic Links

Tags: fitnesse

I am trying to setup external symbolic links using environment variables in Fitnesse.

An environmental variable is set as shown here in the **context.txt** page

```
!define TESTHOME_PATH {D:\Fitnesse\FitnesseRoot\TestHome}
```

I then try and set the Symbolic Links within properties using the following setup

```
Name: Test

Path to Page: file://${TESTHOME_PATH}/Tests/
```

Yet, this error is shown when saving:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: file://${TESTHOME_PATH}/Tests/

I think my setup is correct based on [this reference guide](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.FitNesseWiki.SymbolicLinks).

Any help to use environmental variable in symbolic links would be of use.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues here:

1. The documentation has a typo, file: must be followed with three slashes, e.g. `file:///${MYTEST}`
2. The symbolic link path must contain only forward slashes, not backslashes.